# Index quickly a large dataset on solr

Tags: performance, indexing, solr, dataset

I have few millions of records and I need them to be indexed in Solr. Once they're indexed, they're not going to be changed and the collections are used only for "read". I am following the pattern by posting the xml docs to the REST api and it works fine ... even though it takes some time (configs are optimized for read and cache);

But I was wondering ... is there a better/faster approach - maybe avoiding the HTTP/network layer? Something like working locally to build the collection, copy it to solr server and then add/swap the collection?

One choice could be a custom DIH for a second/backup core and swap when done - but this would mean I would have to "eat" the memory used on solr for caching slowing down searches.

I am searching/hoping for a disconnected solution - like a command line tool, running on a different machine with the configuration optimized for writing, then copy the core on production swapping the old with the new one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few million records should not be an issue.

Check how often you do commit and maybe disable soft commit or make it much higher.

You can also send documents to one Solr instance from multiple clients and get some multi-threading benefits.

And you can certainly write a small SolrJ client to index into a local/embedded core and then swap that core into production.

Comment: "And you can certainly write a small SolrJ client to index into a local/embedded core and then swap that core into production." - I tried to find a way to do it, but no luck so far. I am not a solr-ninja, I am just doing it from time to time. Any idea where I can find a sample to start building from it?

Comment: I am not aware of any super-fresh samples of embedded SolrJ. [My own example](https://github.com/arafalov/solr-indexing-book/blob/master/published/solrj/ClientSolrj.java) is quite out of date by now, as a lot of APIs changed since the book. In any case, I would start from commit and multi-threading changes first.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll go with the embedded version. I have 10M docs and started to push them with 10 different processes (via post.jar). After 5hrs it managed to push few tens of thousands and then solr started to throw OutOfMemory exceptions (virtual machine with 8GB ram - host has 12, 8CPUs - host has 16 and solr has been started in standalone mode with "-m 6g"). Weird ...